# Unable to burn to CDs with Brasero or K3b (cdrecord and cdrao(?)) both fail. What causes this?

Tags: burning

I cannot burn any CDs (first time I've tried since upgrading to 11.10 to my memory). The media I'm using are 56x capable CD-Rs, and I'm using the same DVDrw/Bluray drive that came with my HP laptop (dv7 1020us).

Here is the output k3b (I lost the brasero output somehow):

```
    Devices
-----------------------
Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500S 1.83 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, BD-ROM, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW, BD-ROM] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96R, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

K3b::IsoImager
-----------------------
mkisofs print size result: 77112 (157925376 bytes)

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.2
KDE Version: 4.7.2 (4.7.2)
QT Version:  4.7.4
Kernel:      3.0.0-13-generic

Used versions
-----------------------
mkisofs: 1.1.11
cdrecord: 1.1.11

cdrecord
-----------------------
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
TOC Type: 3 = CD-ROM XA mode 2
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'Optiarc '
Identification : 'BD ROM BC-5500S '
Revision       : '1.83'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x0009 (CD-R)
Profile: 0x0040 (BD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) 
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) (current)
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96R RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 3299328 = 3222 KB
FIFO size      : 12582912 = 12288 KB
Speed set to 2822 KB/s
Track 01: data   150 MB        
Total size:      172 MB (17:08.18) = 77114 sectors
Lout start:      173 MB (17:10/14) = 77114 sectors
Current Secsize: 2048
ATIP info from disk:
  Indicated writing power: 5
  Is not unrestricted
  Is not erasable
  Disk sub type: Medium Type A, high Beta category (A+) (3)
  ATIP start of lead in:  -11634 (97:26/66)
  ATIP start of lead out: 359846 (79:59/71)
Disk type:    Short strategy type (Phthalocyanine or similar)
Manuf. index: 3
Manufacturer: CMC Magnetics Corporation
Blocks total: 359846 Blocks current: 359846 Blocks remaining: 282732
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  16.0 in dummy TAO mode for multi session.
Last chance to quit, starting dummy write in    2 seconds.
   1 seconds.
   0 seconds. Operation starts.
Waiting for reader process to fill input buffer ... input buffer ready.
Starting new track at sector: 0
Track 01:    0 of  150 MB written.
Track 01:    1 of  150 MB written (fifo  96%) [buf  32%] 309.3x.
Track 01:    2 of  150 MB written (fifo  93%) [buf  65%] 351.8x.
Track 01:    3 of  150 MB written (fifo  90%) [buf  96%] 346.3x.
Track 01:    4 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   1.6x.
Track 01:    5 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.5x.
Track 01:    6 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:    7 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.5x.
Track 01:    8 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:    9 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   10 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   11 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   12 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   13 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   14 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   15 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   16 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   17 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   18 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   19 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   20 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   21 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   22 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   23 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   24 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   25 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   26 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   27 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   28 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   29 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   30 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   31 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   32 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   33 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   34 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.5x.
Track 01:   35 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   36 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.5x.
Track 01:   37 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   38 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.5x.
Track 01:   39 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   40 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   41 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   42 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   43 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Track 01:   44 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   45 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   46 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   47 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   48 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   49 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   50 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.4x.
Track 01:   51 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   52 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   53 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   54 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   55 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   56 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   57 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.1x.
Track 01:   58 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   59 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   60 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   61 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   62 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.3x.
Track 01:   63 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.0x.
Track 01:   64 of  150 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]   8.2x.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), write_g1 scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  2A 00 00 00 81 16 00 00 1F 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: F0 00 03 00 00 7A A3 0A 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x0C Qual 0x00 (write error) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 31395 (valid) 
cmd finished after 18.085s timeout 40s
/usr/bin/wodim: A write error occured.
/usr/bin/wodim: Please properly read the error message above.
write track data: error after 67678208 bytes
Writing  time:   79.157s
Average write speed  13.0x.
Min drive buffer fill was 100%
Fixating...
WARNING: Some drives don't like fixation in dummy mode.
Fixating time:    0.001s
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo had 1257 puts and 1067 gets.
/usr/bin/wodim: fifo was 0 times empty and 1014 times full, min fill was 90%.
BURN-Free was never needed.

cdrecord command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=16 -tao -dummy driveropts=burnfree -multi -xa -tsize=77112s -

mkisofs
-----------------------
77112
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
  0.65% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:42:14 2011
  1.30% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:43 2011
  1.96% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:50 2011
  2.61% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:25 2011
  3.25% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:10 2011
  3.89% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:00 2011
  4.54% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:53 2011
  5.19% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:47 2011
  5.85% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:43 2011
  6.49% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:39 2011
  7.14% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:37 2011
  7.78% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:00 2011
  8.44% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:56 2011
  9.09% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:53 2011
  9.74% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:37:50 2011
 10.38% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:26 2011
 11.04% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:30 2011
 11.69% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:34 2011
 12.33% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:38 2011
 12.97% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:33 2011
 13.64% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:37 2011
 14.28% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:40 2011
 14.92% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:42 2011
 15.57% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:45 2011
 16.21% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:47 2011
 16.88% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:43 2011
 17.52% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:46 2011
 18.16% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:48 2011
 18.81% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:50 2011
 19.47% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:51 2011
 20.11% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:53 2011
 20.76% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:50 2011
 21.40% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:51 2011
 22.06% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:53 2011
 22.71% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:54 2011
 23.36% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:56 2011
 24.00% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:57 2011
 24.64% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:54 2011
 25.31% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:55 2011
 25.95% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:56 2011
 26.60% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:58 2011
 27.25% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:59 2011
 27.89% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:00 2011
 28.53% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:57 2011
 29.20% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:58 2011
 29.84% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:38:59 2011
 30.48% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:00 2011
 31.13% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:01 2011
 31.79% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:02 2011
 32.42% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:00 2011
 33.09% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:00 2011
 33.73% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:01 2011
 34.37% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:02 2011
 35.03% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:03 2011
 35.68% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:03 2011
 36.32% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:01 2011
 36.96% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:02 2011
 37.63% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:03 2011
 38.27% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:03 2011
 38.91% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:04 2011
 39.56% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 40.22% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:03 2011
 40.86% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:04 2011
 41.50% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:04 2011
 42.16% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 42.81% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 43.45% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:06 2011
 44.09% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:04 2011
 44.76% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 45.40% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 46.04% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:06 2011
 46.70% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:06 2011
 47.35% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:07 2011
 47.99% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:05 2011
 48.63% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:06 2011
 49.30% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:06 2011
 49.94% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:07 2011
 50.58% done, estimate finish Sun Oct 30 09:39:07 2011

mkisofs calculate size command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -print-size -quiet -volid Crossroads -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2010 SEBASTIAN TRUEG AND MICHAL MALEK -publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bWr4619.tmp -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bBz4619.tmp -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bwD4619.tmp -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bmN4619.tmp

mkisofs command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/genisoimage -gui -graft-points -volid Crossroads -volset  -appid K3B THE CD KREATOR (C) 1998-2010 SEBASTIAN TRUEG AND MICHAL MALEK -publisher  -preparer  -sysid LINUX -volset-size 1 -volset-seqno 1 -sort /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bYM4619.tmp -rational-rock -hide-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bll4619.tmp -joliet -joliet-long -hide-joliet-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3brc4619.tmp -no-cache-inodes -full-iso9660-filenames -iso-level 3 -path-list /tmp/kde-rolandixor/k3bHZ4619.tmp
```

Using `cdrecord` as the backend, I get an error (254), and it claims I may need to change the permissions (which I tried). That doesn't seem to work, and all the Google searching I've done seems useless.

I recall something about power calibration failing - but I was on my way to bed, and later to church, when I was trying to burn the CD - so I did not have the time to record what it was.

---

I have tried:

`sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/wodim` - no go.

---

*BTW - the drive can read CDs just fine, though it takes forever to show what's on them (the laptop is a wee bit old (almost 4 years!), and I've kept upgrading since 8.10 or 8.04, so I think that might be the problem with the speed).*

---

Is there a way around these errors? Or is this a hardware issue? If I need to add more debugging info, let me know.

---

I tried this on another system with 11.10 (another laptop) and it's fine...

---

*(I'm experienced enough so you can ask me to do `dmesg` and all the jazz :D).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I am unable to check up on the status of this issue, but it seems the drive is working fine for the most part. I will probably update if anything changes (since I'm on 12.04 now).

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the drive laser is shot :).

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your optical disk is failing. If you have a USB optical drive on hand, try using that, and see if it works.

Comment: I don't have one to hand, but now I'm upgrading to 12.04, I'll see if I still get the problem. It seems the drive is working fine for most tasks anyway, so I don't think it's failing.